# How to get GPS back to show another process?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I'm going on with GPS enable and disable service I just got it by the following code

Here is the code:

```
public class gps extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?"
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

I used this process for my google maps activity to enable and disable GPS if i goes to setting page after switch on GPS it call backs on onResume method.

Once it come to map it should show another alertdialog message if I call the method on onResume the app chrases.

Here is another alert mess code:

```
public class gps extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
showAlert();
        }else{
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }


Public void showAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
Map.this);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Maps"
.setMessage("Can we use your location "
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
// MY CONTENT
}
.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
// MY CONTENT
}
```

For this a lot with internet to fix but I can't if some have any idea about this please help me friend.

Here is the logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2826)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at com.hubino..Map.onResume(Map.java:392)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1215)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5327)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
07-11 16:35:41.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3841):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: post your logcat then..........

Comment: i'ad posted my logcat please see

Comment: can u plz help me for solve this problem

Comment: Can you post your entire code..I found where your app getting crashed.. If you post the remaining codes, then I hope I can resolve it..